# How str.join works in python

Tags: python, list, join

**For example** Why in the code, the join function, join the the first column of the board list?

```
board=[] # is a list

for i in range(5): # number of rows in the list
    board.append(['O']*5)
    print board

[['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O']]
[['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O'], ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O']]
[['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O'], ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O'], ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O']]
[['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O'], ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O'], ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O'], ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O']]
[['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O'], ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O'], ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O'], ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O'], ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O']]

def print_board(board):
    for row in board:
        print " ".join(row)
print print_board(board)

O O O O O
O O O O O
O O O O O
O O O O O
O O O O O
```

Comment: Whats your expected output? at fist part you have create a 5x5 list and in your function you have joined the rows and printed them.

Comment: `str.join(iterable)` *Return a string which is the concatenation of the strings in the iterable iterable. The separator between elements is the string providing this method.*

Answer (score 2):

In this part of code:

```
for i in range(5):
    board.append(['O']*5)
    print board
```

You are only appending to the `board` list 5 more lists with 5 `0` inside.

In this other part:

```
def print_board(board):
    for row in board:
        print " ".join(row)
print print_board(board)
```

You are printing row by row the elements of the `board` list, but converting them to `string` with `join`.

[`join`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) returns a string which is the concatenation of the strings in the iterable which you pass as a parameter. The separator between elements is the string providing this method.

In your case, `" ".join(row)` would mean:

> Return me the row list with all his elements detached by a blankspace.

And when you do `print " ".join(row)` you're saying:

> Print me the row list with all his elements detached by a blankspace.